# Or condition in if block is only checking the first stmt but not the second stmt

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to login , enter username and pwd and writing a condition if "agree element" is not displayed or "admin header element "is displayed then click on admin element , but my code is only checking I agree element is not displayed and throwing me exception.

```
driver.get("entering url");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
       driver.findElement(By.id("BodyContent_MainContent_MainContentPlaceHolder_UserName")).sendKeys(" entering username");
       driver.findElement(By.id("BodyContent_MainContent_MainContentPlaceHolder_Password")).sendKeys("sending pwd");
       driver.findElement(By.id("BodyContent_MainContent_MainContentPlaceHolder_LoginButton")).click();
       if( !driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='I Agree']")).isDisplayed() || driver.findElement(By.id("admin_header")).isDisplayed()  );
          driver.findElement(By.id("admin_header")).click();
    }
```

Comment: Does your code throw a `NoSuchElementException` and if so: why did you not include that in your question?

Comment: yes, it throws the NoSuchElementException

Comment: The question, as currently presented, seems unrelated to the actual problem.

Comment: @snehajambula Can you summarize your usecase further? What do you want to do if **agree element** or **admin header element** `isDisplayed()`? What do you want to do if **agree element** or **admin header element** is **not** displayed?

Comment: @snehajambula Is your usecase is to click on **agree element** if `isDisplayed()` or else click on **admin header element**?

Comment: @snehajambula Do you want to consider the usecase when **agree element** and **admin header element** both are **not** displayed, what would you like to do then?

Comment: problem got solved!thanks for you time

Answer (score 1):

Use `findElements` instead of `findElement` and check the `size()` of the returned collection to check wether or not an "I agree" element is present.

Comment: I'm adding a little to the answer to clarify, checking the presence of an element using `isDisplayed()` would always throw `NoSuchElementException` when the element is not present. It can be handled by using it in a try block but checking the size of the list of all the elements available for a locator is faster and it avoids handling unneccessary exception.